# Get value of formData in JQuery ajax beforeSend

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-data

I use jQuery ajax to upload file. I append `File` and `Path` to `FormData`. I want to get `File` and `Path` content in ajax `beforeSend`. For example like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("Path", "Gallery/Image");
formData.append("File", $("input[type='file']")[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
    url : "Upload.php",
    type: "POST",               
    xhr: function() {
        // code
    },      
    // code
    data: formData,             
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        // Get formData values in here
    }
});
```

How can I do this work?

Comment: Is this HTML5 (ie10+) or do you need to support IE9 or prior?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `beforeSend` is typically to set headers (instructions) about the data being sent.  For example, when you buy something on Amazon before it's shipped, we need a tracking label on the box.  The label isn't a part of the item being shipped but necessary for the transfer.  Your `formData` is the data is the contents of the package.  You can't send the payload before send in a single request; it almost sounds like teleportation (the data gets there before it's even sent!)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are after here but here is how you can query the file information:  Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/4x4rqc82/

Sample markup:

```
<input type="file" id="myfile" value="">
<br>
<img src="" width="200" style="display:none;" />
<br />
<div id="mypathdisplay"></div>
<div id="fileinfo">FileInfo:</div>
```

Sample code:

```
$('#myfile').change(function (event) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Path", "Gallery/Image");
    formData.append("File", $("input[type='file']")[0].files[0]);
    $('#fileinfo').append('<div>' + "Name:" + event.target.files[0].name + '</div>');
    $('#fileinfo').append('<div>' + "LastModified:" + event.target.files[0].lastModified + '</div>');
    $('#fileinfo').append('<div>' + "LastModifiedDate:" + event.target.files[0].lastModifiedDate + '</div>');
    $('#fileinfo').append('<div>' + "LastModifiedDateUTCDate:" + event.target.files[0].lastModifiedDate.getUTCDate() + '</div>');
    $('#fileinfo').append('<div>' + "LastModifiedDateUTCHours:" + event.target.files[0].lastModifiedDate.getUTCHours() + '</div>');
    $('#fileinfo').append('<div>' + "Size:" + event.target.files[0].size + '</div>');
    $('#fileinfo').append('<div>' + "Type:" + event.target.files[0].type + '</div>');
    var mything = formData; ///.getAll("File");

    var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    console.dir(event.target.files[0]);
    $("img").fadeIn("fast").attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));

    $("#mypathdisplay").html("Temp Path(Copy it and paste in browser address bar) ==> <span class='paths'>[" + tmppath + "]</span>");
});
```

NOTE: You could use this inside the handler as well to simplify it some:

```
var myfile =  this.files[0];
$('#fileinfo').append('<div>' + "Name:" + myfile.name+'</div>');
```